# Evaporating water from a combination of dietary minerals: will it work safely or react?

Tags: heat, elements

I've combined multiple elements dissolved in water into a preferred ratio, but would like to evaporate some of the water to increase the concentration (let's say at 200 $^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ in the oven). The elements in question and the amounts are: 2 mg chromium, 5 mg lithium, 2 mg vanadium, 140 mg iron, and 50 mg boron. The volume of water is about 60 ml.

I would like to know if I can safely do this procedure without a) causing a reaction; and b) evaporating any of the elements.

Comment: Without info about what salts exactly did you use the may be problem with answering this.

Comment: It seems like 200 degrees is overkill. Why not simply boil off the water (maximum temp. 100C), or use vacuum drying at room temperature? I would not expect a reaction from commonly found salts of these elements, plus boron in the form of boric acid.